# How many ways can we distribute 3 marbles in 3 cups?

Tags: probability

if the random variable Y = the number of empty bowls after distributing 3 marbles, randomly, into 3 bowls.

What is the probability distribution of Y?

I believe:
1. There is a 1 to 1 bijection between this problem and the following:
0+0+0, where 0 means 1 marble and + means seperation between bowls.
so 0+0+0 means 1 marble in each.
00+0+ means 2 marbles in the first bowl and 1 in the second. etc

we use the position of the marbles to say 6C3 is the number of ways in which we can distribute the marbles.
6C3=20

Y=0 has only one possible case 0+0+0
y=1 has 6 possible cases 00+0+, 0+00+,0++00,00++0,+0+00,+00+0
y=2 has 3 possible cases 000++,+000+,++000
y=3 has 0 possible cases

However 1+6+3 doesn't equal 20. What is wrong?

Comment: You're argument is correct, but you need to compute $\binom{5}{2} = 10$, not $\binom{6}{3} $.

Comment: I spent so long counting and recounting that I missed that. Thank you, but what do I do now? Should I delete this post? Should I leave it? Should I answer my own question?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you can leave it here! About answering you own question read the reference in the help center!

Comment: the easy to undestand formalism of stars and bars helps a lot ; it is efficient here to compute the whole possibilities and the particular case of an empty cup.

Comment: **Beware:** The outcomes counted using "stars and bars" are not *equally probable* events.

Answer (score 1):

**Beware** The outcomes counted by "stars and bars" are not equally probable events.   The ratio of counts using it will *not* give a correct probability measure.

Rather consider that there are $3^3$ ways to choose bowls for the three marbles, in total.   There are (how many?) ways to choose a bowl to put all three marbles.   That yields $\mathsf P(Y=2)$

> $$\mathsf P(Y=2)={\binom 3 1 1^3}/{3^3}= 1/9$$

There are (how many) *equally probable* ways to put the marbles into three different bowls.   That yields $\mathsf P(Y=0)$

> $$\mathsf P(Y=0)={3!}/{3^3}=2/9$$

Then to calculate $\mathsf P(Y=1)$ we must count the *equally probable* ways to select two bowls and place the three marbles within *so they are not* in the same bowl; then divide by the total ways.   (Or simply subtract the sum of the other probabilities from one.)

> $$\mathsf P(Y=1)={\binom 32(2^3-2)}/{3^3}= 6/9$$